# Agnostic Deserializing with System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json-deserialization, system.text.json, .net-4.8

I'm developping an API client to retrieve json data and try to deserialize it to an object.

The API can return the expected object or an error object:

> `{ "prop1": "value1", "prop2":"value2" }`

> `{ "error": "PLS123", "message":"position laterale de securite" }`

So I'd like to deserialize it to instances of the following classes:

```
public class Foo {
  public string prop1 {get;set;}
  public string prop2 {get;set;}
}

public class Error {
  public string error {get;set;}
  public string message {get;set;}
}
```

What I tried first is to expect the deserialization would throw an exception when trying to deserialize an error to a Foo:

```
string jsonContent = ApiCall();
Foo foo = null;
Error err = null;

try
{
  foo = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Foo>(jsonContent);
}
catch
{
  err = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Error>(jsonContent);
}
```

**But no exception is raised in this case and I get a Foo with null properties.**

Then, I tried to deserialize as a JsonDocument to check error property presence:

```
JsonDocument jsonDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonContent);
Foo foo = null;
Error err = null;

if (jsonDoc.RootElement.TryGetProperty("error", out JsonElement jsonErr))
{
    err = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Error>(jsonContent);
}
else
{
    foo = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Foo>(jsonContent);
}
```

**This is working but it takes much more time to parse and deserialize.**

So, is there a fast way to detect which class to deserialize to?

Comment: With .Net6 you can actually deserialize `jsonDoc` directly, which should be a lot faster (at least you avoid parsing twice).

Comment: Could you determine the result object type by the response code (I assume REST API, so you'll probably get 2xx or 4xx codes) ?

Comment: @freakish it's a dependency of a net48 project, so I'm stuck on netstandard2.0, maybe I could get the source code to deserialize from JsonDocument.

Comment: @sinsedrix you can try installing newer version of System.Text.Json from NuGet. This may break other dependencies though. Downloading the source code is an option as well. You can also utilize some other Json lib, e.g. Newtonsoft.

Comment: @freakish I gain a lot of time passing from newtonsoft to text.json so I won't get back.

Comment: @Fildor This is a great solution in my case!

Answer (score 0):

In your case to avoid the additional check for property (extra parsing), I would create a single class for the result:

```
public class Result {
  public string prop1 { get; set; }
  public string prop2 { get; set; }

  public string error { get; set; }
  public string message { get; set; }

  public bool IsError { get { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(error); } }
}
```

Then, in your logic, first you check `result.IsError` and then handle the result differently.

In my opinion, the question is also in clear separation between receiving result and then using it. For example, to avoid slowdown on extra parsing, you can always deserialize into single `Result` instance, and then, depends on content of its properties, return either `Error` or `Foo` instance.

Comment: @Peter Csala, how do you imagine using the original two different classes after deserialization in the logic? Anyway, you have to check Error instance for null, and then branch your code. How then it is different if you do check of the actual error inside one Result instance?

Comment: @Peter Csala, sorry, I don't really get your comment in relation to the question. For me it sounds like a discussion of in which situations C# is bad.